# Is it possible to edit a post title on user facebook profile using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo, photo-tagging

I have done a facebook application which upload photos into default application album. I found that after the upload, there will be a post displayed on user profile saying 'Smi added 10 new photos to the album xxxxx.'. Is it possible to edit the message above to 'Smi added 1 new photo to the album via xxxapplication'? I am using Graph api to upload the photo. The code I am using to upload is

```
$file = "@".realpath($image); 
$args = array(
    'message' => '',
    "access_token" => $access_token,
    "image" => $file
    );
$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you have no control over the activity feed message for items like that.  The only items you will be able to control when uploading are photo captions, album titles, and tagged users.

Comment: Hi OffBySome, Thanks for the reply